# Displaying command entered to run the trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I am trying to figure out how to display the insert statement, which the user enters. I want it to display after the "Please update the insert statement" text prints. From reading a ton of things online, I found out that you can display the previous command entered on oracle, by entering a "/" sign, and also by running this query 'SELECT * FROM gv$sql WHERE SQL_ID = IDENT_CURRENT('gv$sql')'. I tried using an execute immediately statement in the trigger, using dbms_output.put_line(/), and simply using t0_char('/'); in the query as you see below. Any tips?

```
set serveroutput on
CREATE or REPLACE trigger before_insert_t
before insert on reservations
for each row

DECLARE
rooms_remaining number(5,2);

BEGIN

select roooms_rem into rooms_remaining from reservations where roomno=:new.roomno;

if rooms_remaining = 0 then

    dbms_output.put_line('Insertion now allowed because room ' || :new.roomno || ' is booked!' );
dbms_output.put_line('Please update the insert statement');
--  to_char('/');
    dbms_output.put_line('insert into reservations values ' || :new.roomno  );
--  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt;
end if;
END;
/
show errors
insert into reservations values (99,9);
```

Comment: First, `IDENT_CURRENT` is not a function that is defined in Oracle.  It appears that this is a SQL Server function-- did you implement a custom function named `IDENT_CURRENT` in your system that is modeled after the SQL Server function?  Second, the '/' you're talking about appears to be the SQL*Plus command.  This is not something that you can use in SQL or PL/SQL, it is a client-side command that is specific to SQL*Plus.

Comment: [Documentation for the `/` command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve004.htm) in SQL*Plus, which is all I can think you're referring; it doesn't have any meaning to the server though, it's a client command. And it executes the previous comand, it doesn't display it. You also might not want to assume that the client doing the insert will be set up to handle `dbms_output` as you expect.

Comment: ALERT- `ORA-04091: table reservations is mutating, trigger/function may not see it`

Comment: I copied the wrong one, but I've been trying to use a select statement from the v$sql table to display the last command entered,I am fairly new at this. I am using sql*plus.

Comment: Even if u try using `v$sql` how do you plan to identify "the" `INSERT` statement? do you plan to use `...WHERE SQL_TEXT LIKE 'INSERT INTO RESERVATIONS%'....` ?

Comment: I was hoping to find a way to only return the last executed statement.

Comment: Yes, that is what I planned on doing. Now the only thing is how to execute that command in the trigger

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE or REPLACE trigger before_insert_t
before insert on TEST_TAB1
for each row    
DECLARE
  sql_insert varchar2(1000);    
BEGIN    
  select sql_text into sql_insert 
    from (select sql_text 
            from v$sql 
            where upper(sql_text) like 'INSERT INTO TEST_TAB1%'
            order by first_load_time desc)
   where rownum=1;  
  dbms_output.put_line('Inserting into table SQL is '||sql_insert);    
END;
/

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> insert into TEST_TAB1 values ('Hello');
1 rows inserted.
Inserting into table SQL is insert into TEST_TAB1 values (:"SYS_B_0")
```

You order by `FIRST_LOAD_TIME` and sort it in descending order and select the first row which would be the most recent `INSERT` statement in case there are multiple `INSERT`s.